# Spark Nested foreach

Tags: apache-spark, foreach, nested

I have a Dataset as follows

{"TS":"1461768452",  "IP":"10.10.144.209",  "ID":"KA4aIkFB",  "DEVICE":"Tablet",  "HOST":"krxd.net" }

I am trying to do the following

Group All records by (id,device) and for each group get the latest timestamp.
Then do a distinct on the ID.

Can some one guide me how to do this in Scala?
I know in pig we could a nested foreach loop.Is there a equivalent in spark?

This is what i did so far

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext1.read.json("sample.json")
val df2 = df1.select(df1("ID"),df1("DEVICE"),df1("TS"))
val res= df2.rdd.groupBy ( x => (x(0),x(1) )).mapValues ( x=> x.foreach { x => x(2)})
val res1 = res.mapValues(_.maxBy(_.get(2)))
```

Looks like something is wrong with the last 2 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do such things (groupBy and aggregation by [GroupedData](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData.html)) inside spark sql directly and there is no need to convert DataFrame into RDD:

test json file: test.json

```
{"TS":"1461768452", "ID":"KA4aIkFA", "DEVICE":"Tablet", "HOST":"krxd.net" }
{"TS":"1461768462", "ID":"KA4aIkFA", "DEVICE":"Tablet", "HOST":"krxd.net" }
{"TS":"1461768472", "ID":"KA4aIkFB", "DEVICE":"Tablet", "HOST":"krxd.net" }
{"TS":"1461768482", "ID":"KA4aIkFB", "DEVICE":"Tablet", "HOST":"krxd.net" }
{"TS":"1461768492", "ID":"KA4aIkFB", "DEVICE":"Phone", "HOST":"krxd.net" }
```

scala codes:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("test.json")
df.show
+------+--------+--------+----------+
|DEVICE|    HOST|      ID|        TS|
+------+--------+--------+----------+
|Tablet|krxd.net|KA4aIkFA|1461768452|
|Tablet|krxd.net|KA4aIkFA|1461768462|
|Tablet|krxd.net|KA4aIkFB|1461768472|
|Tablet|krxd.net|KA4aIkFB|1461768482|
| Phone|krxd.net|KA4aIkFB|1461768492|
+------+--------+--------+----------+

val newDF =  df.select("ID", "DEVICE", "TS")
               .groupBy("ID", "DEVICE")
               .agg(max(df("TS")) as "TS")
newDF.show()
+--------+------+----------+
|      ID|DEVICE|   TS     |
+--------+------+----------+
|KA4aIkFB| Phone|1461768492|
|KA4aIkFA|Tablet|1461768462|
|KA4aIkFB|Tablet|1461768482|
+--------+------+----------+

newDF.dropDuplicates("ID").show()
+--------+------+----------+
|      ID|DEVICE|   TS     |
+--------+------+----------+
|KA4aIkFA|Tablet|1461768462|
|KA4aIkFB| Phone|1461768492|
+--------+------+----------+
```

Comment: simple and convincing answer. Can i use same functions in Java too? Because, i never heard about dropDuplicates() function in Java.Thanks.

Comment: you can check the api, dropDuplicates in java: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#dropDuplicates(java.lang.String[])

Comment: You are welcome. If so, you may select my answer as "accepted" :)